# Android run some code at specific time but only once

Tags: android

I want to run some code at specific time, for example at 18:22 but only once.

I try to work with:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

is it good to use:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

or is better to use `handler` to run specific code at specific time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use AlarmManager for such precise timings.

Using a handler will require your app to stay active the whole time, which can have a negative effect on the device's battery. On the other hand, AlarmManager will start up your app when the required time comes, and you don't need to keep it running the whole time.